# How to run fread() to extract data in fixed-size chunks

Tags: c, fread

I am attempting to read from a file and send it over a UDP socket connection in C. I am fairly certain that I am using fread() right, however if I attempt to use fread() again, I get a segfault. I am attempting to send over 1kb packets, and as such, I am trying to extract 1017 characters from the file at a time.

I have tried messing around with the syntax, however I cannot figure out why it is segfaulting. I assume it has to do with me having to reset a pointer for where I am in the file, but I have no clue.

The function is being called as follows:

```
fread(datapkt.data, datapkt.pktLen, 1, filereq);
```

datapkt.data is declared

```
char data[1017]
```

datapkt.pktLen is defined to 1017. I am trying to read one chunk of size 1017, and filereq is the open FILE*

This function works the first time, and if I limit the app to sending only the first data packet, it sends 1017 bytes with no issue. Once a second call to this function happens, the program segfaults. I would like to automate this process, I am using a stop-and-go architecture over UDP where I build a struct with data, serialize it into a char buffer, then send it over and deserialize it. Once the packet is obtained, the client sends an ACK, and once server gets an ACK, it sends the next 1017 bytes, etc until end of file. I have everything working except for this fileread() crash. This is the info provided through gdb bt for the segfault:

```
__memmove_sse2_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:370
#1  0x00007ffff7a6f7db in __GI__IO_file_xsgetn (fp=0x555555757670, data=<optimized out>, n=63747) at fileops.c:1318
#2  0x00007ffff7a633c1 in __GI__IO_fread (buf=<optimized out>, size=63747, count=1, fp=0x555555757670)
    at iofread.c:38
```

Any help is appreciated greatly!

Comment: Impossible to tell without [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I would reference [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). Great reference by a good old professor.

Comment: A backtrace would help you figure out where in your code the crash was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
__GI__IO_fread (buf=<optimized out>, size=63747, count=1, fp=0x555555757670) at iofread.c:38
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

That line is interesting, *particularly* the `size` argument being `63747`. It leads me to believe you are *not* calling it with the argument `1017`.

Whether that's because you are explicitly calling it with some other value, or are calling it with a variable that's been overwritten by your first `fread` is hard to say without seeing more code, but those are the two most likely causes you need to look into.

The *first* thing you should do is, immediately before the call to `fread`, actually *output* the current value of `datapkt.pktLen` to see if something is changing it.

One thing I note with interest though, the value you appear to be using as the second length is `63747` or `249 * 256 + 3`. By a stunning (almost certainly non-) coincidence, reversing those two bytes gives `3 * 256 + 249 == 1017` or the length you *should* be using.

So quite likely an endian issue of some description, something that often happens if you're sending binary information over the wire between systems with different endian-ness, or if you have code that builds values up assuming a certain endian-ness, such as:

```
uint16_t datalen = ucharbuff[0] * 256 + ucharbuff[1];
```

That will give you the wrong value on a `ucharbuff` in little-endian format, where the most significant components are at the *higher* memory addresses.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't look this closely into the backtrace details! Looks like I forgot to use ntoh on the server side to convert endianness. One simple, small mistake :)